# Expose global variable when using Browserify

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, browserify

I use Browserify and would like to use D3.js along with a radar chart component.

```
import 'd3';
import 'radar-chart-d3';
```

The radar chart component returns the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: d3 is not defined`.

I tried using the `insertGlobalVars` option of browserify:

```
browserify: {
    bundleName: 'main.js',
    prodSourcemap: false,
    insertGlobalVars: {
      d3: function(file, dir) {
        return 'require("d3")';
      }
    }
  }
```

However, this does not change anything about the situation.
I know I can just add `require('d3')` at the top pf the radar chart .js file but I'd like to avoid that.

What other way is there to expose the `d3` variable to a global scope so that other files can use `d3`.

Comment: do you use jshint ? if so, you should add "globals": {
        "d3": true,} to your .jshintrc file

Comment: @MayK No, I use ESLint.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in in `package.json`:

```
"eslintConfig": {
  "globals": {
    "d3": true
  }
}
```

Comment: Added it exactly like that but the problem still exists :(.

Comment: do you have <!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8"> set ?